# Automatically un-marshall json body and Request Header both into Java Class, as an extension to @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot, trying to find a generic solution that allows me to map the response headers in the Java POJO directly, without having to manually write the operation going `response.getHeaders()` or `@RequestHeader("Car-Type") carType` and then mapping to the POJO in the method body.

```java
    @GetMapping("/api/headers")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCar(@RequestHeader(value = "Car-Type", required = false) String carType,
                                           @RequestHeader(value = "Car-Color", required = false) String carColor,
                                           @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customer.setCarType(carType);
        customer.setCarColor(carColor);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customer);
    }
```

I wanted it to work automatically without having to specify @RequestHeader since my application has a lot of consumption of RequestHeaders. Below code returns `null` for `carType` and `carColor`, which is expected.

```java
    @GetMapping("/api/headers")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCarAuto(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
// I don't need to set this up manually. if this @RequestBodyAndHeader could map it automatically. 
//        customer.setCarType(carType); 
//        customer.setCarColor(carColor);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customer);
    }
```

Customer Class

```java
@Data
public class Customer {
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    private long OMG;
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String WTF;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    private String LOL;
    @JsonProperty("town")
    private String YOLO;
    @JsonProperty(required = false)
    private String carType;
    private String carColor;
}
```

Comment: Please give some code of what you tried. Or of how to do it manually.

Comment: @Datz Added the code and more details